# Javascript - Orden de ejecución de las funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones

Me ha surgido una duda en relación con el siguiente código sencillito en Javascript:

```js
var count = 0;

exampleFunction();

function exampleFunction() {
  console.log("Llamada a la función:"+ ++count)
}

exampleFunction();
```

Se realiza una primera llamada a la función sin haber definido previamente esa función. Una vez que ejecuto el código no me genera ningún error, cosa que no entiendo ya que según mi criterio primero se tiene que definir la función para poder realizar una llamada a la misma.

Comment: Es porque javascript no es un lenguaje compilado sino interpretado

Answer (score 2):

> Las funciones deben estar dentro del alcance cuando se llaman, pero la
>   declaración de la función se puede izar (aparece debajo de la llamada
>   en el código), como en este ejemplo:

```
console.log(square(5));
/* ... */
function square(n) { return n * n }
```

**¿Qué quiere decir esto?** Que no importa donde se declare una función, esta siempre va a tratarse como si se hubiese declarado arriba del todo de su ámbito de ejecución.

Es por eso que aunque la función se declare abajo de la llamada a dicha función, esta funcione correctamente.

**Referencia:** [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: como referencia este [libro](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch2.md) que con un ejemplo muy basico explica como funciona el [lexico gramatico](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar) en ECMAScript

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error (si es que este existiera) lo obtendrías hasta que ejecutes el código pues JS no es compilado, por lo tanto el interprete al momento de leer tus líneas de código será donde detecte el *posible* fallo o inconsistencia.

Por otro lado si deseas controlar este comportamiento, puedes:

- Declarar una variable con el identificador `let`
- Igualar dicha variable con una función sin nombre
- Cuando trates de invocar a dicha variable en una segmento donde aún no existe obtendrás el siguiente error:

> "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'funciona' before initialization

```
console.log(funciona())

let funciona = function() {
  return 1;
}

console.log(funciona())
```

Donde línea 1 no funcionará pero línea 7 si funcionará

Entonces para evitar lo que mencionas puedes pasar de:

- La declaración de una función

al uso de la sinxtaxis para:

- expresión de función

**Referencia**

- [Sintaxis de funciones en JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones)

Comment: Realmente no obtendrá ningún error en tiempo de ejecución, la declaración de funciones siempre se *eleva* al inicio del contexto actual (en inglés se le llama *hoisting*)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @PabloLozano y perdón por no expresarme de la forma adecuada; la idea era decirle que no vería al momento de escribir un posible error *si es que este llegase a existir* (salvo algún IDE) pero ya noto que no dejé en lo absoluto claro el punto